# TikZ wire cross-section

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have tried to do a wire cross-section:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \clip (-2,-1.1) rectangle (1,1.5);
        \begin{scope}[rotate=-30]
        \fill[orange!50, draw = black] (-3,-1) rectangle (0,1);
        \fill[gray!40, draw = black] (0,0) circle(1cm);
        \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,0) circle(1cm);
        \fill[orange!50, draw = black, dashed] (0,0) circle(0.5cm);
        \end{scope}
        \draw[-stealth,<->] (80:1) -- node[right]{$r_{W}$}(120:0);
        \draw[-stealth,<->] (30:0.5) -- node[right]{$\delta_{SC}$}(30:1);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I put my draw similar to the sketch below? With current vector I and wave-cut upwards.
[image]

Comment: Do you want the cross section to be circular or elliptic? Circular doesn't feel that realistic.

Comment: I agree that elliptic feel more realistic :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you'll like it ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                pgfplots.fillbetween,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5, rotate=-30, >=Stealth,
every edge quotes/.style = {font=\footnotesize, anchor=south, 
                            sloped, rotate=-30, },
decoration={snake, 
            pre =lineto, pre  length=4pt,
            post=lineto, post length=4pt}
                        ]
                        
                        meta-segment length
\draw[name path=A, decorate] 
    (-2,-1) to[bend left=60] (-2,1);
\draw[name path=B]  (-2,1) -| (0,-1) -- (-2,-1);
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B] {fill=orange!50};
%
\filldraw[fill=gray!40] (0,0) circle[x radius=0.5, y radius=1];
\filldraw[fill=orange!50, dashed] (0,0) circle[x radius=0.25, y radius=0.7];
\draw[<->] (0:0) to ["$r_{W}$"]   (75:0.91);
\draw[<->] (30:0.27) to ["$\delta_{SC}$"]   (30:0.56);
\draw[->, very thick] (0,0) -- (1.2,0) node[below left] {$I$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
As ask/suggest @Crazymoomin in his comment, it may be better that the left end of tube is drawn as `random steps`. In this case the options of the `tikzpicture` is:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5, rotate=-30, >=Stealth,
every edge quotes/.style = {font=\footnotesize, anchor=south, 
                            sloped, rotate=-30, },
decoration={random steps, amplitude=2mm, segment length=3mm, % <--- changed 
            pre =lineto, pre  length=4pt,
            post=lineto, post length=4pt}
                        ]
```

Using it in above MWE gives (a broken tube):

[image]

Well, you can use any of `decorations.pathmorphing` options. See chapter *50.3 Path Morphing Decorations` for them.

Comment: Would `random steps` instead of `snake` more closely approximate their image? Hard to tell.

Comment: @Crazymoomin, you may right. I tough abo0t this, but on the end I stay with OP `snake`. I can add it as addendum to answer (ASAP) ...

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, rotate=-30]
\clip[decoration=snake, decorate] (-2.5,-1.4) rectangle (1.5,1.2);
\filldraw[fill=orange!50] (-3,-1) rectangle (0,1);
\filldraw[fill=gray!40] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\filldraw[fill=orange!50, dashed] (0,0) circle[radius=0.5];
\draw[Stealth-Stealth] (80:1) -- node[right]{$r_{W}$}(120:0);
\draw[Stealth-Stealth] (30:0.5) -- node[below]{$\delta_{SC}$}(30:1);
\draw[-Stealth, very thick] (0,0) -- (1.4,0) node[below left]{$I$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Wire cross section]

Answer (score 5):

I made this one with elliptical cross-section based on the hpekristiansen answer:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, arrows.meta}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \clip[decoration=snake, decorate] (-2,-1.4) rectangle (1.5,1.2);
        \filldraw[fill=orange!50] (-3,-1) rectangle (0,1);
        
        \draw [black,fill=gray!40] (0,0) ellipse (0.5 and 1);
        \draw [black,fill=orange!50,dashed] (0,0) ellipse (0.25 and 0.5);
        
        \draw[Stealth-Stealth] (90:1) -- node[right]{$r_{W}$}(120:0);
        \draw[Stealth-Stealth] (270:0.5) -- node[right]{$\delta_{SC}$}(270:1);
        \draw[-Stealth, very thick, red, line width=1mm, font=\large] (0,0) -- node[below]{\textcolor{black}{$I_{SC}$}}(1.4,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `arrows` is deprecated